# How to restart Marathon or any DC/OS services in dc/os Cluster

Tags: dcos

How to restart a service in dc/os as an example marathon or admin router?
i tried the command:- /etc/systemd/system/dcos-marathon.service but no luck.

This question may seem simple but i tried searching in google didn't find answer hence m here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

systemctl restart dcos-marathon

Comment: where should i run this command? on bootstrap server, master server, or agent server?

Comment: depends on the component service. In this case, marathon runs on all master nodes.